# Cordova ant jar not available

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, cordova

Cordova 3.3.0 installed from fresh and PATH fixed with visibility to tools etc.

Build a new bare application
Add android platform

now it starts to go awry -

Following instructions to import to Android Development Tools ( Eclipse ) I get TWO projects created
HelloWorld and HelloWorld-CordovaLib

HelloWorld has errors as it can't see/does not have the the cordova.jar file ( assuming this from past experience )

HelloWorld-CordovaLibs is whats missing from the HelloWorld project all the source to Cordova

Assuming that I need the jar file I dig around and try running ant jar from within the android part of my project

Running ant jar fails -

Target "jar" does no exist in the project "HelloWorld"

which is an ant error telling me it doesn't know how to build target jar.

look at build.xml in the android directory confirms this - no section on "jar" 
A bit more digging on the net and the Apache Cordova git repository seems to intimate that I  should have another file build.xml inside a directory 'framework' with the jar target defined.

Ahhhhh - no framework directory anywhere.

Can anyone work out where this is all going wrong before I tear any more hair out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I followed this guide to create a Cordova 3.3.0 project, import it into Eclipse, and successfully run it on a device from Eclispe: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

You are right that it imports "HelloWorld" and "HelloWorld-CordovaLibs".  This is because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5232, which makes Android now use the CordovaLib instead of the .jar for a variety of reasons (see the bug report.) You should import both projects into Eclipse (I'll change this in the documentation).

If you follow that guide you should be fine. You don't have to build a .jar anymore.

Comment: I have imported both projects into ADT but the HelloWorld app still has compile errors. The import org.apache.cordova.* fails which is odd because the source is all there in the project under CordovaLib

Comment: You need to import the projects into Eclipse, not ADT. When you right click on the `Hello` project, and click Properties, then click "Android"...on the bottom under the Library section you should see "CordovaLib" and it should be checked...is it? (I don't use Eclipse that much but I'm pretty sure you just have to get it configured correctly.) Another thing you can try is making sure that under the "Android" menu, that you have Android 4.4 checked as a Build Target.

Comment: So the Eclipse based Android Development IDE is no good? That seems odd.

Comment: Have tried this with pure eclipse IDE and it still  will not build. somewhat frustrating. Been trying to get this lot going for 2 weeks on and off!

Comment: Although the HelloWorld-CordovaLibs is checked as per your suggestion and the build target is 4.4 I had errors on the HelloWorld project until I did an initial clean on the HelloWorld-CordovaLibs project.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what you mean by ADT - I use Eclipse with the ADT tools installed, I think I downloaded it as a single package from the android website. I thought you were talking about something else though. No, you need to use the Eclipse based tool. So you are saying that you cleaned the Libs project and now everything works fine?

Comment: Nope ADT is a single eclipse download. It's eclipse but branded as ADT.

Comment: Downloaded from dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131310.zip .... should end up being the same thing with all the SDK's and ADT installed.  ......... Moved everything to original 'Eclipse' unbranded installation and yes it all works. Reproduced a new project and imported it into the 'ADT' version and that works too. Needed the initial build to 'kick it off'. @MBillau

Answer (score 3):

steps

1- after create the project i import both "hello" and "hello-cordovaLib"

2- i remove the reference to "hello-cordovaLib" from "hello"

3- build the "hello-cordovaLib"

4- restore the reference to "hello-cordovaLib" from "hello"

5- clean "hello" and run

Answer (score 2):

In short .... The ide ( either eclipse or ADT ) needed the initial build of the sub project to allow the HelloWorld project to 'see' the HelloWorld-cordovaLibs project.

Answer (score 1):

What solved my problem on HelloWorld project in my ADT is :

1. I cleaned both the HelloWorld and the HelloWorld-cordovaLib.
2. Right clicked on HelloWorld-cordovaLib ->properties->Android and verified
       it the isLibrary is checked.
3. I right clicked on HelloWorld proj -> Properties ->Android -> The "is Library part" had Cordova with red check on it then I clicked on "Add" button and again added Cordova to the project which came with "green check" and then removed the red checked cordova.

Cleaned the projects and now its working fine.