# No cordova.jar file in cordova-3.3.0

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

Previously I was working with older version of cordova but just downloaded the new 3.3 version. Now, I am not able to find the cordova.jar file which I need to put in libs folder of android project. I went through google where they have posted about creating the jar file by own, but I was not able to get it properly.

I am using Eclipse for development of the project not any terminal approach.

If anyone can help me to get the jar file or can post link from where I can get this jar file.

Thanks

Comment: did you upgrade your project from the Command line interface?

Comment: Please check this link.I think someone already solved your problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659853/cordova-ant-jar-not-available

Comment: Please see the steps:1) Create new project. 2) then added plugins 3) Then run command ---- $sudo npm install -g phone gap                   4) but node.js should be there 5) export PATH = ${path}:/user/.../adt-bundle.../platform-tools:/user/....adt..../tool 6) $phonegap run android